# updateOrCreate Function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

Code is fine and I'll double check my code but I didn't find anything wrong in my code. This doesn't update or insert address or new user data in any condition.

```php
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'id' => Auth::id(),
        'address' => auth()->user()->address
    ],
    [
        'address' => $request->address
    ]
);

if ($user)
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'add' => $request->address,
        'msg' => 'Address Updated Successfully'
    ]);
else
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'msg' => 'Error Occured'
    ]);
```

Same Code here just taking user_id in parameter

```php
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'id' => $request->id
    ],
    [
        'address' => $request->address
    ]
);

if ($user)
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'add' => $request->address,
        'msg' => 'Address Updated Successfully'
    ]);
else
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'msg' => 'Error Occured'
    ]);
```

Comment: Can you show what's coming in `Auth::id()`?

Comment: Try adding `address` to your `User` Model $fillable ?

Comment: Check if the controller action is within the `auth` middleware to obtain `Auth::id()`.
For user_id in parameter, shouldn't it be `$request->user_id` ?

Comment: Authenticated user id is coming up in Auth::id(). @parth

Comment: yeah let me try model $filable thing for address that may work for me @jef

Comment: @Beast69 did $fillable work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "updateOrCreate" method in UserController, this is not a good practice to make them in the same endpoint. Normally, "updateOrCreate" should be used for secondary type of data. For main data, creating and updating should hit the separate endpoints thus separate methods.

Furthermore, If you have Auth::id(), then you have a user. So there is nothing to create. To update the user, just use update method and get the user with id.

To create a user, use the "store" method pass the values and create it there.